# How to wrap large text inside a row in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have checked most of StackOverflow QA regarding the issue but can't figure the correct implementation:

Kindly suggest me to implement correct modification in `_getItemRow`. Below is the code:

```
 Widget _getItemRow(String item1, String item2, {bool linkify = false}) {
    return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              item1,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            linkify
                ? Wrap(
                    children: [
                      RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text: item2,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .body1
                              .copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                            ..onTap = () async {
                              if (await canLaunch(item2)) {
                                await launch(item2);
                              } else {
                                scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text("Could not open url"),
                                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                ));
                              }
                            },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Wrap(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        item2,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

 ExpansionTile _getExpansionTile(String title, List<Widget> itemWidgetsList) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
      ),
      initiallyExpanded: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: itemWidgetsList),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

 Widget _productGeneralWidget() {
    Widget productGeneralWidget = SizedBox.shrink();
    if (isProductDataReady &&
        ((productDetails.containsKey("sku")) ||
            productDetails.containsKey("slug") ||
            productDetails.containsKey("status") ||
            productDetails.containsKey("type") ||
            productDetails.containsKey("featured") ||
            productDetails.containsKey("total_sales"))) {
      List<Widget> productGeneralWidgetData = [];

      if (productDetails.containsKey("id") && productDetails["id"] is int) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Id: ", "${productDetails["id"]}"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("slug") &&
          productDetails["slug"] is String &&
          productDetails["slug"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Slug: ", "${productDetails["slug"]}"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("permalink") &&
          productDetails["permalink"] is String &&
          productDetails["permalink"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Permalink: ", "${productDetails["permalink"]}"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("type") &&
          productDetails["type"] is String &&
          productDetails["type"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Type: ", "${productDetails["type"]}"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("sku") &&
          productDetails["sku"] is String &&
          productDetails["sku"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Sku: ", "${productDetails["sku"]}"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("status") &&
          productDetails["status"] is String &&
          productDetails["status"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(_getItemRow(
            "Status: ", productDetails["status"].toString().titleCase));
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("catalog_visibility") &&
          productDetails["catalog_visibility"] is String &&
          productDetails["catalog_visibility"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(_getItemRow("Catalog visibility: ",
            productDetails["catalog_visibility"].toString().titleCase));
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("purchasable") &&
          productDetails["purchasable"] is bool) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(_getItemRow(
            "Purchasable: ", productDetails["purchasable"] ? "Yes" : "No"));
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("featured") &&
          productDetails["featured"] is bool) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Featured: ", productDetails["featured"] ? "Yes" : "No"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("on_sale") &&
          productDetails["on_sale"] is bool) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("On Sale: ", productDetails["on_sale"] ? "Yes" : "No"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("virtual") &&
          productDetails["virtual"] is bool) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Virtual: ", productDetails["virtual"] ? "Yes" : "No"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("downloadable") &&
          productDetails["downloadable"] is bool) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow(
              "Downloadable: ", productDetails["downloadable"] ? "Yes" : "No"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("total_sales") &&
          productDetails["total_sales"] is String &&
          productDetails["total_sales"].isNotEmpty) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow("Total ordered: ", "${productDetails["total_sales"]}"),
        );
      }

      if (productDetails.containsKey("backordered") &&
          productDetails["backordered"] is bool) {
        productGeneralWidgetData.add(
          _getItemRow(
              "Backordered: ", productDetails["backordered"] ? "Yes" : "No"),
        );
      }

      productGeneralWidget =
          _getExpansionTile("General", productGeneralWidgetData);
    }
    return productGeneralWidget;
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Product Details"),
      ),
      body: !isProductDataReady
          ? !isError ? _mainLoadingWidget() : Text("Error Fetching Data")
          : RefreshIndicator(
              key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
              onRefresh: fetchProductDetails,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _productHeadlineWidget(),
                      _productImagesWidget(),
                      _productGeneralWidget(),
                      _productPriceWidget(),
                      _productInventoryWidget(),
                      _productShippingWidget(),
                      _productReviewsWidget(),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
      floatingActionButton: isProductDataReady
          ? UnicornDialer(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(100, 100, 100, 0.7),
              parentButtonBackground:
                  Theme.of(context).floatingActionButtonTheme.backgroundColor,
              orientation: UnicornOrientation.VERTICAL,
              parentButton: Icon(Icons.add),
              childButtons: <UnicornButton>[
                UnicornButton(
                    hasLabel: true,
                    labelText: "Edit",
                    currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "edit",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                      mini: true,
                      child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final result = await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => EditProductPage(
                                    baseurl: widget.baseurl,
                                    username: widget.username,
                                    password: widget.password,
                                    id: widget.id,
                                  )),
                        );
                        if (result is String) {
                          fetchProductDetails();
                          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text(result.toString()),
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                    )),
                UnicornButton(
                    hasLabel: true,
                    labelText: "Delete",
                    currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "delete",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                      mini: true,
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )),
              ],
            )
          : SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
```

Below exception is thrown when using this overflow

```
Reloaded 0 of 968 libraries in 1,252ms.
D/FlutterView( 8322): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c104134
D/FlutterView( 8322): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c104134

Performing hot reload...                                                
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)       -I/flutter ( 8322): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8322): The following assertion was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 8322): A RenderFlex overflowed by 187 pixels on the right.
I/flutter ( 8322):
I/flutter ( 8322): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 8322):   Row
I/flutter ( 8322):   file:///C:/Users/itsga/Desktop/flutter/woocommerceadmin/lib/src/products/widgets/ProductDetailsPage.dart:339:9
I/flutter ( 8322):
I/flutter ( 8322): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
I/flutter ( 8322): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and        
I/flutter ( 8322): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 8322): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 8322): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 8322): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 8322): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a        
I/flutter ( 8322): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,       
I/flutter ( 8322): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 8322): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#d8b1b relayoutBoundary=up19 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter ( 8322):   creator: Row ← Column ← Align ← ClipRect ← Column ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← Container ←
I/flutter ( 8322):     AnimatedBuilder ← ExpansionTile ← Column ← Padding ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 8322):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
I/flutter ( 8322):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 8322):   size: Size(360.0, 257.0)
I/flutter ( 8322):   direction: horizontal
I/flutter ( 8322):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 8322):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 8322):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 8322):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter ( 8322):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 8322): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤     
I/flutter ( 8322): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════     

Reloaded 0 of 968 libraries in 2,420ms.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after all hit and trial and with some help, I could able to solve the problem. I have to change `Row` with `Wrap` inside my `_getExpansionTile` function, which is a top-level widget over the `wrap` widget and doesn't play nicely with wrap widget inside it.

Modified code:

```
Widget _getItemRow(String item1, String item2, {bool linkify = false}) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          item1,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: linkify
              ? RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: item2,
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .body1
                        .copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTap = () async {
                        if (await canLaunch(item2)) {
                          await launch(item2);
                        } else {
                          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text("Could not open url"),
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                  ),
                )
              : Text(
                  item2,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  ExpansionTile _getExpansionTile(String title, List<Widget> itemWidgetsList) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
      ),
      initiallyExpanded: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: itemWidgetsList),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it is because `RichText` widget is not wrapped in a `Wrap` Widget easy fix.

```
  Wrap(
                      child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: item2,
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .body1
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () async {
                            if (await canLaunch(item2)) {
                              await launch(item2);
                            } else {
                              scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text("Could not open url"),
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                              ));
                            }
                          },
                      ),
                    ),
                )
                : Wrap(
                      child: Text(
                      item2,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                    ),
                ),
```

Comment: Nope, it was not a problem. linkify option is by default false. I tried wrapping all widget n updated code. But the issue not solved.

Comment: what is the widget that this goes it in your build

Comment: ok try wraping that text widget below ```RichText``` in ```Wrap``` i didn't see that the first time changed code

Comment: is this not the widget causing the overflow